# Combining relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model `Zone`, a model `Entity` and a model `Transit`. `Transit` is minimally defined as:

```
class Entity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entities'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    contained_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entities.id'))
    contains = db.relationship('Entity', backref='container')
    discriminator = db.Column('type', db.String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}

class Zone(Entity):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'zones'}
    routes = db.relationship('Transit')
    (stuff goes here)

class Transit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "transits"
    start = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('zones.id'))
    end = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('zones.id'))
```

`Zone` also has a couple of bits about distance and how defensible it is, but that is irrelevant for this.

- First off, due to the fact that `Zone` is subclassed from `Entity` using single-table inheritance can I reference `zones.id`?
- Secondly, will the `Zone.routes` property merge `Transit.start` and `Transit.end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. no, you need to use the table name, which in your case (Single-table inheritance) is `entities`
2. no, these will not be merged. You can create two relationships, and have a (hybrid) property which would combine both, but this will only be for reading purposes, as when you would like to modify this property (for example, add `Transits`), you would still need to specify both sides (`start` and `end`).
3. I am not sure I understand the question here

**update-1:** as requested in comment, Concrete-Table inheritance code below:

```
class Zone(Entity):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'zones'}
    __tablename__ = "zones"
    id          = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'), primary_key=True)
    @property
    def transits(self):
        return self.transits_from_here + self.transits_to_here

class Transit(Base):
    __tablename__ = "transits"
    id          = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('zones.id'))
    end = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('zones.id'))

    s_zone = relationship(Zone, primaryjoin=(start==Zone.id), backref="transits_from_here")
    e_zone = relationship(Zone, primaryjoin=(end==Zone.id), backref="transits_to_here")
```

Comment: * If I were to add an `id` parameter to `Zone` and shift to joined-table inheritance, would that allow me to specifically target `zones.id`? 
* How would I declare `Transits`? I'm fine with not being able to edit a `Transit` instance from the linked `Zone`?
* I don't understand what I asked either, so thanks for trying. Lesson learned not to ask questions on SO after taking medication that 'may induce drowsiness.

Comment: 1) if by `shift` you mean: add the column and add another table, then yes. 2) will update the answer to include the code. 3) NP :)